# Retrieving Data from Webservice and displaying them in list box

Tags: c#, windows

I'm able to retrieve the datas. However i wasn't abe to bind these datas into my listbox.

XAML File Code

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,140,0,0" Name="lb_AllActivity" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="25">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Border Margin="3">
                                    <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Vertical" Width="420" Height="60">
                                        <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="420" Height="60">
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding DateTime}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Amt}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Msg}"></TextBlock>                    
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

I've the following codes in my CS FIle

```
public partial class Activities : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        DatabaseService.ServiceSoapClient dbService = new DatabaseService.ServiceSoapClient();


        public Activities()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeComponent();
            dbService.getAllActivityAsync("Russell Loh");
            dbService.getAllActivityCompleted += new EventHandler<DatabaseService.getAllActivityCompletedEventArgs>(dbService_getAllActivity);

        }

        public class AllActivity 
        {
            public string TransID { get; set; }
            public string Amt { get; set; }
            public string Cat { get; set; }
            public string SharedNo { get; set; }
            public string Msg { get; set; }
            public string DateTime { get; set; }
        }

        void dbService_getAllActivity(object sender, DatabaseService.getAllActivityCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                string result = e.Result;
                string[] arrayActivity = result.Split('~');

                string[] transID = arrayActivity[0].Split('#');
                string[] amount = arrayActivity[1].Split('#');
                string[] category = arrayActivity[2].Split('#');
                string[] sharedNum = arrayActivity[3].Split('#');
                string[] message = arrayActivity[4].Split('#');
                string[] dateTime = arrayActivity[5].Split('#');

                List<String> Activitylist = new List<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i < transID.Length; i++)
                {
                    string TransID = transID[i];
                    string Amt = amount[i];
                    string Cat = category[i];
                    string SharedNo = sharedNum[i];
                    string Msg = message[i];
                    string DateTime = dateTime[i];


                    //Activitylist.Add(DateTime + "  $" + Amt);
                    Activitylist.Add(DateTime);
                    Activitylist.Add(Msg);
                    Activitylist.Add(Amt);

                }

               lb_AllActivity.ItemsSource = Activitylist;

            }

          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do here but I think...

You are not populating your `ActivityList` or `ItemsSource` of `ListBox` properly

```
           for (int i = 0; i < transID.Length; i++)
                {
                    string TransID = transID[i];
                    string Amt = amount[i];
                    string Cat = category[i];
                    string SharedNo = sharedNum[i];
                    string Msg = message[i];
                    string DateTime = dateTime[i];

                    //create a new instance of activity             
                    AllActivity activity = new AllActivity();  
                    activity.Amt = Amt; 
                    activity.Msg = Msg; 
                    activity.DateTime = DateTime;                    

                    ActivityList.Add(activity);
                }
```

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve datas from webservice

Through my Split, i'm actually spliting the results above (result1, result2... etc)

I'm stil unable to add activity to ActivityList.
What should i do now? I am quite new to Mobile Apps.

Comment: public string getAllActivity(string userName)
     {
         string result1 = "";
         string result2 = "";
         string result3 = "";
         string result4 = "";
         string result5 = "";
         string result6 = "";

         string sql = "EXEC GetAllActivities '" + userName + "'";
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection);
         SqlDataReader reader;

         try
         {
             sqlConnection.Open();
             reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             while (reader.Read())
             {

Comment: result1 += reader[0] + "#";
                 result2 += reader[1] + "#";
                 result3 += reader[2] + "#";
                 result4 += reader[3] + "#";
                 result5 += reader[4] + "#";
                 result6 += reader[5] + "#";  

             }
         }
         catch (Exception) {  }

         return result1 + "~" + result2 + "~" + result3 + "~" + result4 + "~" + result5 + "~" + result6 ;
     }

Comment: The above two comments are actually my codes for the webservice.